# wave + curve modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

i have setted the movement of the butterfly with a wave modifier, but when I try to make the butterfly move along a path with a curve modifier it messes its form and the direction of the wave. I want to attach it to the curve named "trayectoria mariposa"

here is the blend file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i1KmurmMdv8XWT8Zby1lL9GvOK67OnKt/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: please apply scale/rotation to your objects, because this will always make trouble in connection with move along curves. Then upload blend file again

Comment: Ok, I think I now have done that, check the file

Comment: no you haven't. look: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6HrA.png Do you know how to apply scale?

Comment: Ahhhh man my bad I dont know why I thought I just had to do it to the butterfly! Sorry, I now have applied scale and rotation to all of the objects